# In the simplification $\cos(\pi-C)-\cos(-C)=[-\cos(C)-\cos(C)]$, what happened to $\pi$?

Tags: trigonometry

My textbook says that
$$\cos(\pi-C)-\cos(-C)=[-\cos(C)-\cos(C)]$$

I'm struggling to understand what happened to the $\pi$. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe someone ate the pie?  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial; pi is `$\pi$`

Comment: Good joke, @J.W.Tanner !

Comment: To be frank, I ate the pie !

Comment: Boring, right ?

Comment: Well, the answer can be obtained by the reduction formula for $\cos$, I guess ?

Comment: I dunno if you understand what I meant, but here's it : computing trigonometric ratios of compound angles wrt $\pi$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$...

Comment: I don't clearly remember the name, but that's what came to my mind.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner 's answer works, but what about the thing I said ?

Answer (score 3):

$\cos(\pi-C)=\cos(\pi)\cos(C)+\sin(\pi)\sin(C)=-\cos(C)$,

using the [difference formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Sum_and_difference_formulas), along with $\cos(\pi)=-1$ and $\sin(\pi)=0$.

Comment: also $\cos(0-C)=\cos(0)\cos(C)+\sin(0)\sin(C)=\cos(C)$

Comment: I visualize this as: \pi is half a circle, so the angles (\pi - C) and (C) are mirror images across the right angle (\pi / 2), so their cosines have the same magnitude but opposite sign.

Comment: @Joe, please use mathjax. It works in comments too...

Comment: The pitty is that, with all of that, the *pie* disappeared while I enjoy it ! This is too sad.